# VS2019 failing to attach to debugger after upgrade

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2019

I have just upgraded Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 to Version 16.11.34 and am now getting the error message

> Failed to launch debug adapter. Unable to launch browser "Could not connect to debug target at at http://localhost:57529"

The application is set to access server http://localhost:58809/ and changing that to 57529 does not fix the problem.
Reverting to the previous version of VS2019 is messy and not guaranteed to fix the problem.
The application is AspNet.Mvc version 5.2.7 and .NET 4.8 on Windows 11
Restarting/rebooting did not fix the problem
How do I fix this.

Comment: I also posted on Super User but that post was migrated here (and so I deleted it). On Super User @harrymc answered but his post is no longer visible. Of the option he suggested disabling script debugging fix the problem

Comment: Have you fired-up Wireshark and taken a look at what network traffic is being exchanged? Also, what debug-protocol have you selected? If this is for a .NET program then it should be using DCOM which doesn't use `http://`.

Comment: When you say "_The application is set to access server_" are you referring to the msvsmon port, or your application's port? Are you using IIS Express, the full version of IIS, or some other host web-server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your situation, you could check the below things:

1, whether the port is avaliable. if the port is already taken by another process, kill that process.

2, Whether there is other previous debugging windows.

3, Change the browser.

4, Disable JavaScript Debugging in VS options:
[image]

Comment: It was script debugging that fixed it. However, moving to VS2022 was an even better solution. Thanks.